# Do Flavored Instant coffee have added sugar content

Tags: instant, flavored-coffee

Recently I fond some interest on flavored instant coffee from brands like Nescafe and other brands.
Flavors as Hazelnut, Caramel, Vanilla, Toffee as such are quite attractive, but since I am on sugar restriction I wonder from these "Artificial" or "Natural" flavors as say in the Ingredients description have any added sugar contents to it to enhance the flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ingredients and nutrition facts on the package. Particularly carbohydrates. Coffee and artificial sweeteners have no carbs, so if you see carbs, it's probably all sugar. Generally the answer is yes, they have added sugar. That's how they make flavors like those you mention taste so sweet.

Comment: While I agree with the major part of the answer, “sweet” can also come from artificial sweeteners. Learned to read the labels carefully thanks to a food intolerance...

Comment: While checking the ingredients I found a component is used called  - Acesulfame Potassium. After some internet search found this element as a calorie-free sweetener and is up to 200 times sweeter than regular table sugar. This is apart from their description "Flavor and Artificial Flavor" within that list.
Also they have 1 net carb per tablespoon serving.